# getting a user-inputed variable in django template wihtout using forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a django template which also has a div element that takes in a user_inputed value.
When the value is entered, I call a javascript function say onSubmit(user_input)

```
<input type="text" class= "inputtext" onKeyPress="return onSubmit(this.value)">
```

Now in this onSubmit() function which now has the user-inputted value user_input, I want to be able to use url patterns to a direct to a view, like

```
function onSubmit(user_input) {window.location = "{% url myview user_input %}";}
```

The problem here is that since user_input is empty when the template is loaded, the url-view reverse lookup gives an error. Is there a way to trigger this lookup only when the onSubmit function is called.

I know form is an alternative, but it just feels like it'll be an overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL via AJAX:

views.py:

```
def get_url(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    args = reguest.GET.get('args', [])
    kwargs = request.GET.get('kwargs', {})
    try:
        url = django.core.urlresolvers.reverse(name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    except NoReverseMatch:
        url = None
    return django.http.HttpResponse(url)
```

urls.py

```
#...
('^url$', get_url)
#...
```

js:

```
function onSubmit(user_input) {
    var args = [user_input];
    jQuery.get('/url', {'args': args}, function(data) {
        var url = data;
        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        } else {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if your URL rule is simple enough, you can use some placeholder when resolving and URL, and before submitting the form you should replace it with real input:

```
var fakeUrl = '{% url myview "%s%" %}';
function onSubmit(user_input) {
    window.location = fakeUrl.replace('%s%', user_input);
}
```

Comment: thanks, the fake url one is the simple idea I was looking for!

Comment: Just noticed I've missed some “var”s in the JS, so if you used this code you better check if you're missing them too.

Comment: Also, if one of solutions worked for you, you should accept the answer so that people will see this question is solved. (Also, I will gain more rep, he-he)